# Python encoding using ASCII

Tags: python, ascii

I am designing a program that will encode. messages imported from a csv. It will do this by converting them their ASCII value, adding 2 to them and then converting them back to characters.

My current problem is that while my code will encode each character in each string the messages are now no longer joined together.
Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
#importing csv file and allowing it to be read from
import csv
ifile = open("messages.csv","rb")
reader= csv.reader(ifile)

#creating lists
plain_text=[]
plain_ascii=[]
encrypted_ascii=[]
encrypted_text=[]
latitude=[]
longitude=[]
#appending csv data to separate lists
for row in reader:
    latitude.append(row[0])
    longitude.append(row[1])
    plain_text.append(row[2])

#encoding messages
encrypted_text=[[chr(ord(ch)+2) for ch in string] for string in plain_text]
print plain_text
print encrypted_text


ifile.close()
```

The current output:

['A famous Scottish victory in the First War of Scottish Independence - bit.ly/1yIAb8Q', "How high is Scotland's tallest mountain? - bit.ly/1q3Rj6D", 'What is the traditional instrument most often linked with Scotland? - http://#bit.ly/1lNdrk3', "A prickly problem Scotland's national symbol - bit.ly/1q3REpQ", 'Name the largest city in Scotland - bit.ly/T4OEuU']
[['C', '"', 'h', 'c', 'o', 'q', 'w', 'u', '"', 'U', 'e', 'q', 'v', 'v', 'k', 'u', 'j', '"', 'x', 'k', 'e', 'v', 'q', 't', '{', '"', 'k', 'p', '"', 'v', 'j', 'g', '"', 'H', 'k', 't', 'u', 'v', '"', 'Y', 'c', 't', '"', 'q', 'h', '"', 'U', 'e', 'q', 'v', 'v', 'k', 'u', 'j', '"', 'K', 'p', 'f', 'g', 'r', 'g', 'p', 'f', 'g', 'p', 'e', 'g', '"', '/', '"', 'd', 'k', 'v', '0', 'n', '{', '1', '3', '{', 'K', 'C', 'd', ':', 'S'], ['J', 'q', 'y', '"', 'j', 'k', 'i', 'j', '"', 'k', 'u', '"', 'U', 'e', 'q', 'v', 'n', 'c', 'p', 'f', ')', 'u', '"', 'v', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'v', '"', 'o', 'q', 'w', 'p', 'v', 'c', 'k', 'p', 'A', '"', '/', '"', 'd', 'k', 'v', '0', 'n', '{', '1', '3', 's', '5', 'T', 'l', '8', 'F'], ['Y', 'j', 'c', 'v', '"', 'k', 'u', '"', 'v', 'j', 'g', '"', 'v', 't', 'c', 'f', 'k', 'v', 'k', 'q', 'p', 'c', 'n', '"', 'k', 'p', 'u', 'v', 't', 'w', 'o', 'g', 'p', 'v', '"', 'o', 'q', 'u', 'v', '"', 'q', 'h', 'v', 'g', 'p', '"', 'n', 'k', 'p', 'm', 'g', 'f', '"', 'y', 'k', 'v', 'j', '"', 'U', 'e', 'q', 'v', 'n', 'c', 'p', 'f', 'A', '"', '/', '"', 'j', 'v', 'v', 'r', '<', '1', '1', 'd', 'k', 'v', '0', 'n', '{', '1', '3', 'n', 'P', 'f', 't', 'm', '5'], ['C', '"', 'r', 't', 'k', 'e', 'm', 'n', '{', '"', 'r', 't', 'q', 'd', 'n', 'g', 'o', '"', 'U', 'e', 'q', 'v', 'n', 'c', 'p', 'f', ')', 'u', '"', 'p', 'c', 'v', 'k', 'q', 'p', 'c', 'n', '"', 'u', '{', 'o', 'd', 'q', 'n', '"', '/', '"', 'd', 'k', 'v', '0', 'n', '{', '1', '3', 's', '5', 'T', 'G', 'r', 'S'], ['P', 'c', 'o', 'g', '"', 'v', 'j', 'g', '"', 'n', 'c', 't', 'i', 'g', 'u', 'v', '"', 'e', 'k', 'v', '{', '"', 'k', 'p', '"', 'U', 'e', 'q', 'v', 'n', 'c', 'p', 'f', '"', '/', '"', 'd', 'k', 'v', '0', 'n', '{', '1', 'V', '6', 'Q', 'G', 'w', 'W']]

Comment: Are you looking for `''.join(mylist)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the inner lists.

```
[''.join(chr(ord(ch)+2) for ch in string) for string in plain]
```